# Way to update / refresh / reschedule project plan after adding a vacation / changing calendar

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

I created a project plan using Project 2010 (not server). I had set the task schedule mode to "Auto Scheduled" and entered the necessary tasks. Since it is a single person project I also added one person to the "Resources" of the file, assigned that resource to all the tasks, and leveled the project.

After the plan was entered and tasks were leveled I figured the calendar was not correctly set (in UAE the weekend is Friday and Saturday instead of Saturday and Sunday). I updated the default calendar (Standard) of the project by going to *Project* > *Change Working Time* > *Work Weeks* and changed them as needed. However after doing this, the tasks are still scheduled over Friday and Saturday even though I have marked them as non-working days in the standard calendar.

I tried the following for the tasks to refresh, but was unsuccessful:

1. Updated all tasks to use the "Standard" calendar in the project
2. Enabled the option where tasks do not ignore resource calendars
3. Added a constraint "As Soon As Possible"
4. Executed "Level All"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the standard calendar, there is also a resource calendar that can take precedence over the project calendar.

1. Go to the Resource Sheet view.
2. Double-click on a resource.
3. Click "change working time."
4. Click on the Work Weeks tab.
5. Click the Details... button
6. Ensure both Friday and Saturday are highlighted under "Select Days."
7. Tick the "set days to nonworking time" radio button.
8. Click Okay until the dialog box is closed.
9. Verify your changes in the Resource Usage view.  You should see that days that are non-working are blue-gray and have no hours scheduled in them.

One caveat: scheduled hours with actuals recorded against them probably will not move.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mark-Poncelet. 

This is an old question and I do not have Project 2010 with me now as we have started using Project 2013. The latest version does not have the above issue.

I am marking your answer as accepted as it looks like that should have been the issue.